# Volume bounded by a sphere of radius $1$ in 4 dimensions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, spheres

I want to express the volume enclosed by a hypersphere of radius $1$ with a quadruple integral, in four dimensions. I know that the equation of the sphere is $x^2 + y^2 + w^2 + v^2 \le 1$. However, I don't know how to proceed and I'm having trouble with the limits.

Note: I don't want to find the volume; I just need the starting point.

Comment: x^2+y^2+w^2 <= 1 is a 3-sphere, you need to add a z^2. Also, you will only need a triple integral.

Comment: @Penguino actually, a 4-sphere needs five variables, and it is a quadruple integral. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere): *For any natural number n, an n-sphere of radius r is defined as the set of points in (n + 1)-dimensional Euclidean space which are at distance r from a central point, where the radius r may be any positive real number.*

Comment: in case this goes anywhere, the easiest way to do this is induction increasing the dimension by 2 each time, doing a double integral in polar coordinates. The result in $\mathbb R^n$ is $\frac{(\pi/2)^n}{(n/2)!},$ where the factorial needs to be interpreted in terms of the gamma function when $n$ is odd. In $\mathbb R^4$ the result is $\pi^2/2.$

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 + w^2 \le 1$ is a $3$-ball, not a $4$-sphere.

Comment: A related post question, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V_n(r)$ be the volume of an $n$ dimensional ball.

$$\int_{-r}^r \! V_n\left(\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x = V_{n+1}(r)$$

Let $t = \dfrac{x}{r}$. Then:

$$\begin{align}V_{n+1}(r) &= \int_{-r}^r \! V_n\left(\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x \\ &= r\int_{-1}^1 \! V_n\left(\sqrt{1-t^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x\end{align}$$

Because $V_3(r) = \frac{4}{3}\pi  r^3$:

$$\begin{align}V_{4}(r) &= \frac{4\pi r^4}{3}\int_{-1}^1\!\left(\sqrt{1-t^2}\right)^3 \mathrm{d}t \\ &=  \frac{4\pi r^4}{3}\underbrace{\int_{-1}^1\!\sqrt{1-t^2}}_{\text{Half unit circle}} \, \mathrm{d}t  - \frac{4\pi r^4}{3}\underbrace{\int_{-1}^1t^2\!\sqrt{1-t^2}}_{\text{Even function}} \,\mathrm{d}t \\ &= \frac{4\pi r^4}{3}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{8\pi r^4}{3}\int_{0}^1\!t^2\sqrt{1-t^2}\, \mathrm{d}t\end{align}$$

Now consider $\displaystyle \int \! t^2\sqrt{1-t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t$. The appropriate substitution is $t = \sin(u)$ and we can re-write our integral as $\displaystyle \int \! \sin^2(u)\cos^2(u) \, \mathrm{d}u = \int \! \sin^2(u)(1-\sin^2(u)) \, \mathrm{d}u =  \int \! \sin^2(u) \, \mathrm{d}u +  \int \! \sin^4(u)\, \mathrm{d}u$.

By reduction formulas we (eventually) reach:

$$\displaystyle \int \! \sin^2(u)\cos^2(u) \, \mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{8}\left(u + 2\sin^3(u)\cos(u)-\sin(u)\cos(u)\right) + C$$

$$\displaystyle \int \! t^2\sqrt{1-t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{8}\left(\sin^{-1}(t) + 2t^3\sqrt{1-t^2}-t\sqrt{1-t^2}\right) + C$$

Every term in this integral is zero at the endpoints except the $\sin^{-1}(t)$ so we find that $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \! t^2\sqrt{1-t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{\sin^{-1}(1)}{8} = \frac{\pi}{16}.$$

Plugging this into our volume formula we find that:

$$\begin{align}V_{4}(r) &= \frac{4\pi r^4}{3}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{8\pi r^4}{3}\int_{0}^1\!t^2\sqrt{1-t^2}\, \mathrm{d}t \\ &= \frac{2\pi^2 r^4}{3} - \frac{\pi^2 r^4}{6} \\ &= \frac{\pi^2r^4}{2}\end{align}$$

Therefore: $$\boxed{V_4(1) = \dfrac{\pi^2}{2}}$$

Comment: I've been reading your solution and trying to understand the following: why the square root have been raised to 3 before replacing $V_3(r)$? Isn't clear for me.