# Volume 4-dimensional sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying Fubini's Theorem and Change of Variables Theore in class, and one of the exercises from last year exam was calculate the volumen of the 4D sphere. I searched on Internet how can I do that applying only the theorems I mentioned before, including polar and espherical coordinates. First, I tried to compute the integral:

$$I=\int_{-R}^R \int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2-z^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2-z^2}} 1 dwdzdydx$$

where $R$ is the radius of the sphere and its equation would be $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2 \leq R^2$, but it's a tedious work and I give it up. My question is how can I solve easily this problem applying a change of variables. I know there is a general expression for the volume of $n$-dimensional sphere, but I'm interested in this particular case. Thank you.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/736030/328173).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the inner integral with respect to $w$ and then change to spherical coordinates.